# OnBackPressedCallback is being called, but app is not going back

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I recently updated my dependencies to include the `OnBackPressedCallback` change from an interface into an abstract class.

I have set things up according to the new documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back#kotlin) but I feel like things are not working as they should.

My fragment's `OnCreate` looks a lot like the documentation:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            backPressed()
    }
}
```

When I press the back button, the code in `backPressed()` is run, but nothing more happens.

I have tried calling `handleBackPressed()` and `requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()` and `requireActivity().onBackPressed()` from inside the callback, but those all cause a StackOverflowError because it seems to run that callback recursively.

There has got to be something really obvious I am missing...

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you have an enabled `OnBackPressedCallback`, then you've said that you'll handle the back button, so of course nothing else runs.

Comment: I need to be able to do some stuff before going back. I can do stuff now, but I can't seem to make it go back.

Comment: if your activity override ```onBackPressed()```  and it have some logic for the fragment onBackPress then please remove that part and after that it will works as expected

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you register an `OnBackPressedCallback`, you are taking on the responsibility for handling the back button. That means that no other on back pressed behavior is going to occur when you get a callback.

If you're using [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/), you can use your `NavController` to pop the back stack:

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
    backPressed()
    // Now actually go back
    findNavController().popBackStack()
}
```

Comment: Ah ok. It seems like I might have been relying on a bug/unintended behavior in the earlier alpha releases. This could actually explain some weird stuff I was working around. Thanks!

Comment: This is not working for me. The thing is it was working in alpha but it's shows error now when i changed to stable version.

Comment: @AbrahamMathew - sounds like you should create a new question with your code that you're having an issue with.

Comment: @ianhanniballake - I have added a callback in the single activity and in some of my fragments that require consuming the BACK button. However, I have noticed that the addCallback() for the fragment must be called in onResume(). If I add prior to this lifecycle callback, and perform a screen rotation, the order in the mOnBackPressedCallbacks is not correct with the activity being first (in reverse order of course). Now if I do not ever rotate the screen, I can call the addCallback() in the fragment even in onViewCreated() and the fragment's callback is called first as expect.

Comment: @pigswig - yes, you cannot rely on the activity's Lifecycle, as mentioned in [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133272537) as it is not nested within the fragment lifecycle. You can certainly use the no Lifecycle versions within your activity to ensure they are always on the bottom of the stack.

Answer (score 25):

> There has got to be something really obvious I am missing...

You forget to disable your custom callback in you fragment before asking Activity to handle back pressed.

My solutiuon suitable for me:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        final OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
               if (/*situation to handle back pressing*/){
                //here handle your backPress in your fragment
                } else {
                   setEnabled(false); //this is important line
                   requireActivity().onBackPressed();
                }
            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    }
```

Comment: "onBackPressed()" is now deprecated, so use "getOnBackPressedDispatcher().onBackPressed()"

Answer (score 9):

This works for me in `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0`

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
        this,
        object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Fragment back pressed invoked")
                // Do custom work here    

                // if you want onBackPressed() to be called as normal afterwards
                if (isEnabled) {
                    isEnabled = false
                    requireActivity().onBackPressed()
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Nice approach!!

Answer (score 4):

You can also remove callback instead of setting enabled if it's no longer needed. I use it with nested graph like this because when you touch back in a nested nav graph with it's NavHostFragment, it removes it from main fragment back stack instead of opening last fragment in nested nav graph.

```
   // Get NavHostFragment
    val navHostFragment =
        childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nested_nav_host_fragment)

    // ChildFragmentManager of the current NavHostFragment
    val navHostChildFragmentManager = navHostFragment?.childFragmentManager

       val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {

        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {

            val backStackEntryCount = navHostChildFragmentManager!!.backStackEntryCount


            if (backStackEntryCount == 1) {
                // We are at the root of nested navigation, remove this callback
                remove()
                requireActivity().onBackPressed()
            } else {
                navController?.navigateUp()
            }
        }
    }

    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, callback)
```